# the selected directory is not valid tomee home idea

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I use Intellij idea. I imported maven project, I checked it out from repository, set up java sdk for it, then tried set up tomcat configuration - set up home directory, e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\ApacheSF\Tomcat, but idea tip says that

> the selected directory is not valid tomee home idea

So when I try to start server, it says the same error.

PS. BTW, how to configure artifact for deployment?

Comment: For Tomcat installation you should use Tomcat configuration, not Tomee.

Comment: oh, thank you! For the first time I didn't understand, now I've got it right. thanks! :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

you should add Tomcat Server  not a TomEE Server

you can check it by setting->Application Servers  and you can see it:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: :) Perfect answer.